# How to create distributed cluster environment for Distributed Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have went through documentation of Tensorflow Distributed Environment, But I cant find anywhere how to setup a cluster suitable to Tensorflow.

Currently I have 10 number of servers where I want to start training a model, But I would like to know the dependencies that I need to install on all the cluster servers except tensorflow library.

OR

Is it enough if I specify the cluster specifications in the python code that I write for distributed training with the IP address of workers and parameter servers Or is there anything that I am missing?

```
tf.train.ClusterSpec({
"worker": [
    "172.09.09.09:1290",
    "172.10.10.10:2040",
    "172.11.11.11:3060"
],
"ps": [
    "172.12.12.12:8080",
    "172.13.13.13:8080"
]})
```

I can find everything else in the tensorflow documentation. Should I build a cluster similar to apache spark?

Please help for the right documented flow of setup for tensorflow cluster or if I  am missing something help me with the simple answer you can.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can create a cluster and install Cloudera Manager on it, then one can try to install tensorflow library on it and use Spark to perform operations on your data:

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/install_cluster_template.html

Once you have your cluster you can do as you were initially doing and run tensorflow on Hadoop:

https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/hadoop

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run one script on each server. With same code. Each script gets some input as arguments to setup itself. You can have a look here: https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/community/en/docs/deploy/distributed.md